# Error: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I was trying to compile the app but these errors  showed up what should I do?

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0
>   Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0
>   Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:23.4.0

The source code is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android 
{
    signingConfigs {}
    compileSdkVersion  21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig 
    {
        applicationId "com.boonex.oo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
    buildTypes 
    {
        release 
        {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    } 
}

repositories 
{
    jcenter() 
}

dependencies 
{
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1' 
}
```

Comment: post your `build.gradle` please !

Comment: @BOUTERBIATOualid  The build.gradle-                                                              `buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
`

Comment: No, i mean try to edit your question and post your `buil.gradle`. you can't post it in comment

Comment: @BOUTERBIATOualid yea alright

Comment: have you tried @Ironman answer ?

Comment: @BOUTERBIATOualid yea i am trying , i am relatively new to android development thats why maybe i made mistaked

Answer (score 1):

Try an earlier more specific version of the Facebook SDK.

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

bro.. just look at that.. your compileSdkVersion is 21. so you are not able to use higher version of appCompat gradle. for that first you have to update your sdk to 23.

you can see my gradle and it should be like that:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.apple"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile project(':library')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.3.jar')
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-vector-drawable'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

you can see that my compileSdkVesion is 23 so my each com.android.support gradle is 23.

sorry to mention lately.. you also need to change class-path for avoid compatibility issue of latest version.

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

and this all thing is only possible when you upgrade your sdk first.

Comment: i have upgraded to the latest but my laptop is having trouble with that i mean it starts running really slow i might have to try this on my computer

Comment: well.. i hope it solve your problem.. and do not forget to approve my answer if you satisfied..